# C# Join Group query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using this query:

```
var result =
    from i in dc.TFFiles                    
    where i.Tid == tid                    
    group i by new { i.Title, i.Type } into gr
    join c in dc.FCategories on gr.FirstOrDefault().CatId equals c.Id
       select new { id = gr.FirstOrDefault().id, Title = gr.FirstOrDefault().Title, Version = (from cv in gr select cv.Version).Max() };
```

But if there are these TFFiles:

```
   id   |   tid   |   Title    |   Type   |    Version
    0   |    15   |  File1     |   Type1  |      0
    1   |    15   |  File2     |   Type1  |      0
    2   |    15   |  File1     |   Type1  |      1
    3   |    15   |  File1     |   Type1  |      2
```

I will get back :

```
   id   |   tid   |   Title    |   Type   |    Version
    0   |    15   |  File1     |   Type1  |      2 (wrong version - id)
    1   |    15   |  File2     |   Type1  |      0
```

Instead of:

```
   id   |   tid   |   Title    |   Type   |    Version
    3   |    15   |  File1     |   Type1  |      2 (correct version - id)
    1   |    15   |  File2     |   Type1  |      0
```

How I can change the query to get the correct result?

Comment: Can't you just select the max id? Or are there situations where that would return the wrong result?

Comment: I want to select the file with max Version because I am not sure if getting the max id witll be always correct

Comment: How about this then: `id = gr.OrderByDescending(item => item.Version).FirstOrDefault().id`

Comment: @pritaeas that worked! if you want post it as answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion in the comments was to get the max id, but that might return the wrong id.

The second suggestion was to use the following:

```
id = gr.OrderByDescending(item => item.Version).FirstOrDefault().id
```

which would get the id from the group with the highest version, by using a descending sort.

One thing remains: should there be identical records where only the id differs, then the id returned might not be the last one. Assuming that's not an issue.